# The request is missing a Valid API Key while using Youtube Data API v3

Tags: reactjs, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the key and show the result on console but its not working. I am using React.js for this purpose.

```
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = "MY_Key Here";

export default axios.create({
 baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
   part: "snippet",
   maxResults: 5,
   key: KEY,
  },
});
```

and App.js contain this

```
onTermSubmit = async (term) => {
  const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
    params: {
      q: term
    },
  });
  console.log(response);
};
```

Everytime i execute this it says "the request is missing valid api key" domain="Global" reason-"forbidden" and status="Denied".

Comment: I know you can't share your actual API key here but is it actually valid? In  Google APIs, create a project, generate the key via then enable it. Follow [this process](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)  if you haven't already and maybe add `/` at the end of your `baseUrl`.

Comment: Yes the API i am using is from Google. I have tried the same process with more than 1 project and also tried regenerating KEY. IF you need API key for test than please tell me i am just learning things.

Comment: Do log on console the complete URL you're invoking to see that it has the required `key` parameter.

Comment: @MuhammadHassaanAther Ah I see. I'd be happy to take a look. Please send me an email with the key so that it is not public here. mattcroak718@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved now. The params in above code needed to be called inside App.js file

Answer (score 2):

make sure you add all those
params: {
part: "snippet",
maxResults: 5,
key: KEY,
}

in your App.js and remove it from youtube.js
params: {
q: term
},

here,

and end code of your App.js gonna look like

params: {
part: "snippet",
maxResults: 5,
key: KEY,
q: term
}

its because after your baseURl from youtube.js it directly go for your App.js params which consist of only one thing thats {q} so pgm never gets a chance to actually read the key

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a new component for your api key
the code bellow worked for me!

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import axios from "axios";
const KEY = "Your API_KEY";

class App extends React.Component {
  onTermSubmit = async (term) => {
    axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
      params: {
        part: "snippet",
        maxResult: 5,
        key: KEY,
        q: term,
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
const result = await youtube.get("/search", {
      params: {
        part: "snippet",
        maxResults: 5,
        key: KEY,
        q: term,
      },
    });
```

The problem is with the params part, it can't parse params from two different file I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably in your current project `axios` is not installed as a dependency. Therefore, you are using an old version of `axios` which does not support setting multiple params. I suggest you check `package.json` and install axios by `npm install --save axios`. I understand the application works by moving params into `app.js` but it is not the solution of the problem but a workaround.